# How many CRS / EPSG codes are there?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

I assume the answer to the number of CRS is "nobody knows", given that everybody can define their own CRS willy-nilly.

So maybe it's better to ask: How many EPSG-registered CRS are there? I haven't found an easy way to scrape the total number of EPSG codes in the various lookup tools.

Are there other well-endowed libraries of CRS such as EPSG? If so, how many CRS do they entail?

Comment: Download the latest version of the EPSG database from epsg.org and count yourself.

Comment: @mkennedy has done that so you don't have to, see their answer. ;-) if you are familiar with MS Access, MySQL, Oracle, or PostgreSQL it's worth downloading the epsg database (free, after registration) and having a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset v9.3](https://www.epsg-registry.org) (it's now up to 9.4.1 online), there are 5822 coordinate reference systems. This includes projected, geographic/geodetic, vertical, and a few engineering ones. Newer geographic/geodetic will include 2D, 3D, and geocentric/3D Cartesian versions.

There are also 760 deprecated CRS.

Disclosure: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG Registry.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a lookup tool, you might want to consider looking at the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) [CRS Definition Resolver](https://external.opengeospatial.org/twiki_public/CRSdefinitionResolver/WebHome), which is implemented using Rasdaman SECORE (Semantic Coordinate Reference System Resolver).

The OGC CRS Name Resolver is accessible at the following service endpoints:   ​

- http://www.opengis.net/def/axis (for Axis Identifier URLs)
- ​http://www.opengis.net/def/crs (for CRS Identifier URLs and CRS Template URLs)
- ​http://www.opengis.net/def/crs-compound (for Compound CRS URLs)
- ​http://www.opengis.net/def/equal (for semantic CRS URL comparison)
- ​http://www.opengis.net/def/crs-query (for general XQuery requests)

*Ref: http://rasdaman.org/wiki/SecoreUserGuide*

Note it doesn't resolve all EPSG code versions, or URN identifiers generally.  It gives access to EPSG codes and OGC codes inter al.

Comment: Thanks, but I've worked with CRS for years, I just never researched how many "registered" CRS are out there. Hence this "simple" question :) .

Answer (score 1):

There are 9.906 different spatial references on http://spatialreference.org/ref/?page=199 available. The front page says "4362 EPSG references" but also the last update was in year 2013.

Comment: I get 9906 that way: 198 pages with 50 each, plus 6 on page 199. 9906 does equal all of the reference types listed on the spatialreference.org homepage: EPSG (4362) + ESRI (447) + IAU2000 (2380) + spatialreference.org (2717)

Comment: Oh, you're right! I just saw "SR-ORG:54:" on the first page and assumend there are 54 each.

Comment: That's a good-enough approach, and a good-enough answer, I think. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: But doesn't have the OGC ones

Comment: I don't think thats right. It surely has OGC ones (OGC provides EPSG 4326, right?). So there is a chance that there are more spatial references from OGC, but i can't find any list like on spatialreference.org

Comment: Not sure what you mean by OGC provides. OGC services may provide data in EPSG:4326, but OGC the organization does not define it.  By OGC ones I meant those defined by OGC, like: http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/

Comment: spatialreference.org has been abandoned by it's developers many years ago, and has lagged behind a few EPSG releases and corrections.

Answer (score 1):

[epsg.io](http://epsg.io) is a modern webservice, which is "Powered by EPSG database 9.4", the current registry, but also has other CRS definitions. You can [browse the source code](https://github.com/klokantech/epsg.io), including their SQLite database [gml.sqlite](https://github.com/klokantech/epsg.io/blob/master/gml/gml.sqlite), which contains the URN identifier (e.g. `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326`), and the source xml used to define each CRS.

Here is my tally query for the different CRS types:

```
SELECT substr("xml", 6, instr("xml", ' ') - 6) AS crs_type,
       deprecated, count(*) AS count
FROM gml
WHERE id LIKE '%crs%'
GROUP BY crs_type, deprecated
ORDER BY crs_type, deprecated;

crs_type     deprecated  count     
-----------  ----------  ----------
CompoundCRS  false       269       
CompoundCRS  true        7         
Engineering  false       20        
Engineering  true        2         
GeodeticCRS  false       778       
GeodeticCRS  true        400       
ProjectedCR  false       4666      
ProjectedCR  true        350       
VerticalCRS  false       207       
VerticalCRS  true        1
```

There are [extra codes from PROJ](https://github.com/klokantech/epsg.io/tree/master/extra_codes_proj4_4.8.0.2), including 474 from esri.extra, and 21 in other.extra. So I guess the full tally of CRS definitions at http://epsg.io is 7195.

Answer (score 1):

This helps explain why at least three of the CRS registers exist: https://committee.iso.org/files/live/sites/tc211/files/Resources/GuideToCRSRegistries3.pdf

(Peter Parslow, chair of ISO/TC 211)

Answer (score 0):

[Spatialreference](http://spatialreference.org/) knows 4362 EPSG-codes.

Comment: Does that include their versions, for example if we look at URN identifier pattern `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4610` the `::` part is to allow versions

Comment: http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0 gives 5686 then there's http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/8.5 and http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/8.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Esri, as of ArcGIS Pro 2.3 alpha and ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 alpha (so far only a few new objects have been added), has:

```
projected crs: 5467
geographic crs: 734
vertical crs: 305
```

I think the counts omit deprecated objects.

Note: Esri only has 2D geographic CRS (unlike EPSG) but does have ellipsoidal height-based vertical CRS that are combined with a 2D geographic CRS to make the equivalent of an EPSG 3D geographic CRS. Esri also have a bunch of custom Minnesota geographic CRS. They're used in a set of county-level projected CRS that try to minimize the grid-vs-ground differences due to the projections.

Disclosure: I work for Esri.